# Multiple timers on one Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, timer

Modified [Halfway there]
Thank you YowE3K, after your comments the code has been modified but yet it is not working as it should be...
Both timers run independently and fine but only when they run separately. At the very moment when I turn both going, they start counting on every 2 seconds instead of one as it should be. I know it is maybe related to this part "Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "Sheet1.setImmediate" but I don't know how to specify the cell here. Currently they both add one second to Sheet1 when they go together.

Additionally the issue with the timers starting from 00:00:00 after reopening the document stays.

Here is the code - please note that this one is for ToggleButtons:

```
Dim StopTimer           As Boolean
Dim SchdTime            As Date
Dim Etime               As Date
Dim SchdTime2           As Date
Dim Etime2              As Date
Const OneSec            As Date = 1 / 86400#
Private Sub Start_Stop_1_Click()
If Start_Stop_1 = True Then
StopTimer = False
SchdTime = Now()
[K3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "Sheet1.setImmediate"
Else
StopTimer = True
Beep
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Start_Stop_2_Click()
If Start_Stop_2 = True Then
StopTimer = False
SchdTime2 = Now()
[K4].Value = Format(Etime2, "hh:mm:ss")
Application.OnTime SchdTime2 + OneSec, "Sheet1.setImmediate"
Else
StopTimer = True
Beep
End If
End Sub
Sub setImmediate()
If Start_Stop_1 = True Then
[K3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
SchdTime = SchdTime + OneSec
Application.OnTime SchdTime, "Sheet1.setImmediate"
Etime = Etime + OneSec
Else: StopTimer = True
'Don't reschedule update
End If
If Start_Stop_2 = True Then
[K4].Value = Format(Etime2, "hh:mm:ss")
SchdTime2 = SchdTime2 + OneSec
Application.OnTime SchdTime2, "Sheet1.setImmediate"
Etime2 = Etime2 + OneSec
Else: StopTimer = True
'Don't reschedule update
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a first glance guess, but possibly your `Application.OnTime` calls to `setImmediate` are overriding one another? Ie. once one is sheduled you can't schedule another one at the same time.

Comment: The code for the second timer is within an `If` statement which checks that the first timer is running.

Comment: Thank you! I made s slide modification and now both timers can run Independently.
However there are two more issues now :)
When I stop them at certain count (lets say the first one is on 00:04:30 and the second on 00:00:20), if I start the second one again - it goes from 00:04:30.... Either one takes the highest value from both when it starts again. I would prefer to have them running from their last value each.
And when I save the document and open it again - the last counting value is visible, but when I click on start again, it starts from 00:00:00

Comment: If you want to keep their values separate, use separate variables - don't use `SchdTime` and `ETime` for both.  And if you need to initialise the values, you could probably do that when you first start the timers.

Comment: There is another one, separately the timers work fine now but when both are "on" they start counting two seconds each instead of 1 as it should be. Do you think that part should be fixed 'Application.OnTime SchdTime, "Sheet1.setImmediate"' and if yes how I can specify the location? It gives me an error when I try to change this part...